# SSH reverse port forward on EC2 aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, portforwarding

I used to have an ssh reverse port forwarding from my local computer to a remote EC2 AWS server on port 9999. (9999 for both machines.)

It used to work, but I created a new instance, and now it doesn't anymore. (Half working.) I'm not sure what I did to make it work back then... (Or something was changed.)

I have a process running on my computer on port 9999 and I want it to listen to the port 9999 of my EC2.

On my computer, `curl "127.0.0.1:9999"` is working.
But I want the code `curl "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:9999"` to work, for now it doesn't, giving me the error `curl: (7) Failed to connect to ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com port 9999 after 59 ms: Connection refused`

EC2 Security group is set to open 9999 on TCP for 0.0.0.0/0.

I create the forwarded port with the command :

`ssh -R 9999:localhost:9999 -i "/home/example/XXX.pem" ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com`

The connection ssh is established without errors.
Inside this ssh session I can even do `curl "127.0.0.1:9999"` inside and IT IS WORKING. Reaching my local computer.

But the request from the web isn't... (`curl "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:9999"` doesn't work...)

The path is good, if I install apache2 on port 80 `curl "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:80"` is working. (port 80 is added the same way to the security group)

I did `sudo ufw disable`, same problem.

Do you have an idea what I'm missing ?

EDIT : On the `ssh -R` forward session on the EC2 :

`ubuntu@awsserver:~$ php -S 0.0.0.0:9999 -t .`
`[Wed Dec 14 16:35:11 2022] Failed to listen on 0.0.0.0:9999 (reason: Address already in use)`

BUT, if I open a normal ssh session, I can run `php -S 0.0.0.0:9999 -t .`, the code `curl "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:9999"` is working everywhere as expected.

So... it is telling me that the port is already used (By the ssh -R command), but is closed when I try to connect to it... I don't get it.

Comment: `127.0.0.1:8888` seems to be a typo.

Comment: @jarmod Sorry typo on this post, not the code. Edited.

Comment: Be aware of [What's the difference between 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0?](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0) and ensure your server is listening on the correct IP.

Comment: BTW why are you expecting to be able to curl the EC2 hostname:9999 and have that resolve to the local port forward? You'd typically connect to localhost:9999. Do you have a local DNS override resolving the EC2 hostname to localhost?

Comment: I agree with @jarmod. If you are pointing to `ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:9999`, then the request will go straight to that host. It won't go via your port forwarding connection.

Comment: I want to connect from other machines, that's why I need to use the ec2 public IP link. (In fact I'm using alexa skills.) It used to work, alexa's servers were able to reach my local computer through the ec2 instance, but I can't make it work again...

Comment: So you’re doing the opposite of a typical SSH tunnel with EC2? You want the EC2’s port 9999 to be port-forwarded to your local machine port 9999? Are you sure this worked previously where you initiated the tunnel on your local computer?

Comment: Yeah, this is why I'm using ssh -R and not -L. `curl ec2-xx-xx:9999` code doesn't work either on my phone 4G, from the internet. (But it is supposed to work nevertheless from local machine.) Something is blocking it, but I don't get what is... I highly suspect something AWS/EC2 related, or I forgot something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer wasn't EC2/AWS related.

It's a security feature from SSH that I had to disable : `GatewayPorts yes`

Comment: Do take note that the hash `#` symbol before a line in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` refers to a comment, so remember to uncomment the line to allow the `GatewayPorts` config to work. `#GatewayPorts yes` -> `GatewayPorts yes`. Else the config wouldn't apply.